# Reliance on unit in a referenced unit's implementation

Tags: delphi

I use C++ Builder mainly, but am using Delphi more for particular projects. In one project I have a package library (written in Delphi) and I am writing a simple testing application (also in Delphi).

The Delphi package compiles fine.

The Delphi application includes the units that are being tested (on a form by 
form basis).

In my application I have defined a protected class data member (I think 
Delphi programmers normally refer to these as Fields) and so I have included the unit for this class in the interface section of the unit.

The application doesn't compile, as it says it needs a unit which is referenced in the uses cause of the *implementation* section of the unit included in the interface section (actually in a unit referenced by that unit's interface uses clause).

Why is this? The whole point of building a library is so that the code in it can be accessed without knowing the details.

Summary of situation:

Form Unit

```pascal
interface

uses
  ..., LibraryUnitA, LibraryUnitB, ...
```

LibraryUnitA

```pascal
interface

uses
  ..., LibraryUnitB, ...
```

LibraryUnitB

```pascal
interface

uses
  ...

implementation

uses
  ..., LibraryUnitC, ...
```

When I compile the form unit I get an error that LibraryUnitC cannot be found (it's in a different directory). Opening the error to 'unfold' it I see that it says that Unit LibraryUnitC is used by LibraryUnitB, Unit LibraryUnitB is used by LibraryUnitA

But the 'missing' unit is only used in the implementation uses clause, not the interface uses clause.

I have checked that I have the use of runtime packages turned on.

Why does the compiler need it?

---

More data as requested:
The units only use basic data types.
I want to consume a library unit so I need to know its interface, not its implementation.

```pascal
unit frm_DSTests;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  xxDatasetFactory, xxDataset;

type
  TfrmDSTests = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    edPath: TEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    edCoName: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    edUuidString: TEdit;
    btnLoad: TButton;
    Label4: TLabel;
    edNewName: TEdit;
    btnWrite: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnWriteClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    Factory: TxxDatasetFactory;
    Dataset: TxxDataset;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmDSTests: TfrmDSTests;

implementation

 ...
end.
```

```pascal
unit xxDatasetFactory;

interface

uses
  Classes, xxDataset;

type
  TByteArray = array of Byte;

  TxxDatasetFactory = class
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure ReadCompanyFile(Locations: TStringList; CompanyFileName: String);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function MakeDatasetAndLoad(DatasetFolder: String): TxxDataset;
    function MakeDataset(DatasetFolder: String): TxxDataset;
  end;

implementation

  ...
end.
```

```pascal
unit xxDataset;

interface

uses
  Classes, xxSetupDTA;

type
  TxxDataset = class abstract
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    _szDatasetFolder: String;
    _szUuidString: String;
    _szVatNumber: String;
    _blLoaded: Boolean;
    _nMajorVersion: Integer;
    _szVersion: String;
    _szCompanyName: String;
    _blAllowUpdates: Boolean;
    _blModifed: Boolean;

    procedure _AfterLoad; virtual;
    procedure _BeforeLoad; virtual;
    procedure _CheckLoad;
    function  _GetAllowUpdates: Boolean;
    function  _GetCompanyName: String;
    function  _GetCompanyNameLength: Integer; virtual;
    function  _GetCompanyNameOffset: Integer; virtual;
    function  _GetDatasetFolder: String;
    function  _GetMajorVersion: Integer;
    function  _GetUuidString: String;
    function  _GetUuidStringLength: Integer; virtual; abstract;
    function  _GetUuidStringOffset: Integer; virtual; abstract;
    function  _GetVersion: String;
    procedure _Initialise; virtual; abstract;
    procedure _Load(SetupReader: TSageSetupDTA); virtual;
    procedure _LoadWatermark;
    procedure _SetAllowUpdates(NewValue: Boolean);
    procedure _SetCompanyName(NewValue: String);
    procedure _SetUuidString(NewValue: String);

  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(szDataSetFolder: String); virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    procedure Load;

    property AllowUpdates: Boolean read _GetAllowUpdates write _SetAllowUpdates;
    property CompanyName: String read _GetCompanyName write _SetCompanyName;
    property DatasetFolder: String read _GetDatasetFolder ;
    property UuidString: String read _GetUuidString write _SetUuidString;
    property Version: String read _GetVersion;
  end;

implementation

  ...

end.
```

```pascal
unit xxSetupDTA;

interface

  uses
    Classes;

  type
    TByteArray = array of Byte;

    TxxSetupDTA = class
    protected
      { Protected declarations }
      _szDatasetFolder: String;
      _fsFile: TFileStream;
      _blWriteMode: Boolean;

      procedure _CheckOpen;
      procedure _CheckOpenForWrite;
      function  _GetSetupFilename: String;
    public
      { Public declarations }
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy; override;

      procedure Open;
      procedure OpenForWrite;
      procedure Close;
      function ReadSpacePaddedBytes(nOffset, nLength: Int64; Buffer: PByte): Integer;
      function ReadSpacePaddedString(nOffset, nLength: Int64): String;
      procedure SeekTo(Position: Int64);
      function WriteBytes(nOffset, nLength: Int64; Buffer: PByte): Int64;
      function WriteNullPaddedString(nOffset, nLength: Int64; szData: String): Int64;
      function WriteSpacePaddedString(nOffset, nLength: Int64; szData: String): Int64;
      function WriteSpacePaddedNullTerminatedString(nOffset, nLength: Int64; szData: String): Int64;

      property DatasetFolder: String read _szDatasetFolder write _szDatasetFolder;
    end;

implementation

  uses
    SysUtils, StrTools;
...

end.
```

Compiler error is:

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] frm_DSTests.pas(8): F2613 Unit 'StrTools' not found.
  frm_DSTests.pas(8): Unit 'StrTools' is used by 'xxSetupDTA'
  frm_DSTests.pas(8): Unit 'xxSetupDTA' is used by 'xxDataset'
  frm_DSTests.pas(8): Unit 'xxDataset' is used by 'xxDatasetFactory'
```

I don't understand why it's trying to access the 'StrTools' Unit which is internal to the package.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is the actual error message? What does the Form declaration actually look like? Is the Form gritting to use something that is in LibraryUnitC?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - thanks for you interest, I have included (proabably too much) code and the compiler error messages.  I had tried to strip this to the minimum in the question but I appreciate my problem may not have been clear.

Comment: Does `TxxDatasetFactory` or `TxxDataset` use anything from `StrTools`? Is anything in `StrTools` marked as `inline`? I see no reason for the compile error unless your app is NOT referencing the library correctly and is looking for the individual source files, which it shouldn't be. BTW, your library has multiple declarations of `TByteArray`. You should be using the RTL's `TBytes` instead. Or at least declare `TBytesArray` in a common unit

Comment: Have you enabled runtime packages in your application? And included the relevant package in the list of runtime packages?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - The StrTools unit is used in the implementation section of all three of the library units listed here. Nothing in it is marked as inline. Checking to see that the app is linking to the runtime library I could not see it loaded in the debugger ... added the library to runtime packages, removed the location of the missing unit from the search path and I can compile, run and I see it loading the package. Your comments put me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't dealt much with packages and only a long time ago, so that might be  might be totally off track...  But have you made sure the *.DCP file of your package was in the search path?

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt - I had enabled runtime packages, but as per my comment to Remy just now the package was not included ...

Comment: @REmy Lebeau - I take on board your comments regarding the defintions of TByteArray - I have been handed this code which was originally written in Delphi 7 I think and it also struck me as odd. Thanks again for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the problem was that the package I was using had not been added to runtime packages.  (I should have spotted this).

As the package was not linked, Delphi was trying to include the referenced source in the project --- and hence it needed to process the implementation section and not just the interface section.

Many thanks for the useful comments that steered me in the right direction!